# On simplifying $mR_m/m^2R_m$ where $m$ is maximal ideal of $R$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, localization, maximal-and-prime-ideals, local-rings

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $m$ be a maximal ideal ; consider the local ring $R_m$ got from localizing $R$ at $m$ ; then $mR_m$ is its unique maximal ideal .  Then is it true that $m/m^2 \cong mR_m/m^2R_m$ ? If this is not true in general ; is it true atleast when $R$ is a Noetherian UFD ?

Comment: It is true since $m/m^2$ is supported on $m$ only.

Comment: Yes, it is true: see [Milne's notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/CA210.pdf) , Proposition 6.7, page 22. Milne adds an irrelevant noetherian hypothesis in the statement, which he does not use in the proof !